# how to remove symbolic link 'safely' without deleting file?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, symlink

While following a tutorial online ([How to Start PostgreSQL Server on Mac OS X via Homebrew](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x/)) and ran the command `$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents` how to remove this symbolic link without causing some failure?

before command-run state

```
$ cd /usr/local/opt/postgresql/
$ ls
COPYRIGHT           README              include
HISTORY             bin             lib
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json        homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist  share

$ cd /Library/LaunchAgents 
$ ls
com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.plist      
com.cisco.anyconnect.notification.plist 
com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
```

after command-run state

```
ls -l /Library/LaunchAgents 
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  667 Nov 12  2020 com.cisco.anyconnect.gui.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  664 Nov 12  2020 com.cisco.anyconnect.notification.plist
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  104 Jun 10 23:24 com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
```

Can

```
$ rm com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
```

be used to remove the symbolic link and **not** the file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will remove only the symbolic link and not the underlying file. But your original `ln` statement can only have created a link for `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`, and the other links must have been created by something else, so I wouldn't remove them.